# Where are unassigned promises and their associated Handlers stored

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

```
new Promise(executor).then(onFulfilment);

function executor (resolve, reject) {
  function runOnTimerCompletion(){
    resolve("Timer complete")
  }
  setTimeout(runOnTimerCompletion, 1000);
}

function onFulfilment(input){
  console.log(input)
  return input
}
```

The call to Promise constructor returns a promise object (let's call it `originalpromise`). `originalpromise` has status: `pending` and value: `undefined`

Immediately in line 1 we call the then method on the `originalpromise` object which returns a *brand new* promise object - let's call it `nextpromise`. `nextpromise` has status: `pending` and value: `undefined`

When runOnTimerCompletion is called 1000ms later, `resolve` runs - which updates `originalpromise` status to `resolved` and `originalpromise` value to `"Timer complete"`

At that point `onFulfilment` is executed - `onFulfilment()` - and it returns `"Timer complete"`. Our `nextpromise` now has status: `resolved` and value: `"Timer complete"`

Three questions:

1. Where is the `onFulfilment` function that is called on the resolution of `originalpromise` stored?
2. Where are `originalpromise` and `nextpromise` stored - given they're not assigned to anything.
3. And related to (2) - how does `onFulfilment` know to execute on `originalpromise` resolution. Is it referenced by `originalpromise` or does `originalpromise`'s resolution instruct `nextpromise` that its resolved
   and that's what initaites the execution of `onFulfilment`

Answer (score 1):

> Where is the onFulfilment function that is called on the resolution of originalpromise stored?

It's stored in the instance data of the promise whose `.then()` handler was called.  When the promise is resolved, it will call each of the `.then()` handlers in the order they were registered.

> Where are originalpromise and nextpromise stored - given they're not assigned to anything.

In your code, the original promise isn't "stored" anywhere in particular.  It is not garbage collected immediately because the `executor` scope is still alive (due to the `setTimeout()`) and the `resolve()` implementation which can still be called by live code has a reference to the original promise.

> And related to (2) - how does onFulfilment know to execute on originalpromise resolution. Is it referenced by originalpromise or does originalpromise's resolution instruct nextpromise that its resolved and that's what initaites the execution of onFulfilment

`resolve` that is passed to the executor function has a reference to the promise that it pertains to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is the instance data of the `originalpromise` - I don't think it's possible to view it in chrome dev tools for example?

Comment: Additional question: how does the resolve function represent the reference to the `originalpromise` [is there spec/docs I can see the way resolve is working - when I console.log it it's native code - can I view that?]

Comment: @javascriptttt - Promise instance data is private.  You can't view it directly.

Comment: @javascriptttt - There are several different ways `resolve()` could work.  It can even be implemented in pure Javascript with a closure or with `.bind()` (see the [Bluebird promise library source](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) if you really want to look at a Javascript implementation.  You could also look at the [Chrome V8 source code](https://github.com/v8/v8) to see how they do it in native code.

Comment: Thanks for these - really helpful. I'm still unclear on the mechanism by which `onFulfilment` is associated with `originalpromise` and `nextpromise`. It is attached to the `originalpromise` instance somewhere (but this is private) and called immediately after resolve is called. And `onFulfilment`'s return value is then assigned to the `nextpromise` value. Do you have a sense of how `onFulfilment` is associated (in its definition) with `originalpromise` and in its return value with `nextpromise` - thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's true you don't have a direct reference variable to the `new Promise`, but you don't need to declare a variable in order to operate on it. For example, it's just like

`document.querySelector('div').addEventListener(...`

The reference to the div you selected is not saved in a variable, but you can still operate on the object on the same line.

The `nextpromise` reference is truly lost, though: you basically declare it(
`new Promise(executor).then(onFulfilment);`
)

and don't assign it to anything, so there's no way to get it later. *The promise object still exists, it's just impossible to reference.*